# In latex, the integral symbol '\int' displays as '\Delta' in the compiled pdf, why?

Tags: latex

This happens in some (but not all) documents, where '$\int$' in an equation displays as '$\Delta$' in the compiled pdf. For those documents, I tried both Winedt and Overleaf and the same things just happen.

The problem can be replicated by using the following codes in the main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{autart}
\pagestyle{plain}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Generalized $t$-Distribution Noise Model\thanksref{footnoteinfo}}
\thanks[footnoteinfo]{Acknowledgement...}

\author[AuthorCategory1]{Author 1}\ead{author1@somewhere}
\author[AuthorCategory2]{Author 2}\ead{author2@somewhere}

\address[AuthorCategory1]{Address 1}
\address[AuthorCategory2]{Address 2}

\begin{abstract}
---
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

The autart.cls can be found online, for example at https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/514508/filename/autart.cls

You will get a result like this: [image: incorrect integral]

And from my own exploration, the problem can be solved surprisingly if changing the title from

```
\title{Generalized $t$-Distribution Noise Model\thanksref{footnoteinfo}}
```

to

```
\title{Title\thanksref{footnoteinfo}}
```

And you will get the correct integral symbol as follows: [image: correct integral]

It seems that you can also solve the problem by removing the "esint" package, or change the document class from autart to article. I guess there is some conflicts defined in these class/packages, maybe, and result in this funny phenomenon.

Is there a way to solve the problem without changing the title, while using autart document class and esint package?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a link to this documentclass? It is not included in texlive by default...

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. If I use some random version of the class found on the internet and puzzle together your code fragments, it works fine and I do get an integral symbol

Comment: I have revised the question to contain the minimal reproducible code. Thanks.

Comment: Minimal non-working example: `\documentclass{autart}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
\title{$t$}
$\int $
\end{document} 
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, the problem is in the `\no@harm` macro your class defines, which redefines `\protect`. You can work around the problem by removing this defintion like this:

```
\documentclass{autart}

\pagestyle{plain}
\date{\today}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\no@harm}{\def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}}{}{\typeout{patch ok}}{\typeout{patch fail}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{esint}


\setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Generalized $t$-Distribution Noise Model\thanksref{footnoteinfo}}
\thanks[footnoteinfo]{Acknowledgement...}

\author[AuthorCategory1]{Author 1}\ead{author1@somewhere}
\author[AuthorCategory2]{Author 2}\ead{author2@somewhere}

\address[AuthorCategory1]{Address 1}
\address[AuthorCategory2]{Address 2}

\begin{abstract}
---
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Though I don't know the deep mechanism, it solved my problem for sure.